# Try to mount SMB share on NAS and get "Operation not supported"

Tags: cifs, smb, nas, synology

I have several Synology NAS, running DSM 6.2.2-24922 Update 5, which I successfully mount on Ubuntu 18.04 with:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.x.y/folder_name -o username=user,password=???????,uid=1000,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 /local_mount_point
```

I have bought a new one, which is running DSM 6.2.4-25556.  I attempt to mount in the same way and I get this error:

```
mount: /local_mount_point: mount(2) system call failed: Operation not supported.
```

EDIT

I removed the vers=1.0, and the error changed to

```
//192.168.x.y/folder_name does not exist
```

Enable SMB Share is enabled on the new NAS, with the same settings as the others.

My smb.conf on the new NAS is:

```
[global]
printcap name=cups
winbind enum groups=yes
include=/var/tmp/nginx/smb.netbios.aliases.conf
min protocol=SMB2
security=user
local master=no
realm=*
passdb backend=smbpasswd
printing=cups
max protocol=SMB3
winbind enum users=yes
load printers=yes
workgroup=WORKGROUP
```

And my smb.share.conf is:

```
[folder_name]
recycle bin admin only=yes
ftp disable modify=no
ftp disable download=no
write list=nobody,nobody
browseable=yes
mediaindex=no
hide unreadable=no
win share=yes
enable recycle bin=yes
invalid users=nobody,nobody
read list=nobody,nobody
ftp disable list=no
edit synoacl=yes
valid users=nobody,nobody
writeable=yes
guest ok=yes
path=/volume2/folder_name_1
skip smb perm=yes
comment=""

[folder_name_2]
recycle bin admin only=yes
ftp disable modify=no
ftp disable download=no
write list=nobody,nobody
browseable=yes
mediaindex=no
hide unreadable=no
win share=yes
enable recycle bin=yes
invalid users=nobody,nobody
read list=nobody,nobody
ftp disable list=no
edit synoacl=yes
valid users=nobody,nobody
writeable=yes
guest ok=yes
path=/volume1/folder_name_2
skip smb perm=yes
comment=""
```

(For interest, the smb.conf on one of the NAS which are working is:

```
[global]
printcap name=cups
winbind enum groups=yes
include=/var/tmp/nginx/smb.netbios.aliases.conf
security=user
local master=no
realm=*
passdb backend=smbpasswd
printing=cups
max protocol=SMB2
winbind enum users=yes
load printers=yes
workgroup=WORKGROUP
```

)

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Remove the `vers=1.0` option and try again

Comment: That has changed the error, so progress.  I now get 
"//192.168.x.y/folder_name does not exist"
Of course I may be doing something silly now, but I've double checked everything and I don't think it's a typo.

Comment: For that you'll need to share your server's `smb.conf`. If it were a QNAP it would be under `/etc/config`, but I don't know where Synology keeps it

Comment: Do I then add that as an argument to the mount line?

Comment: Copy the `smb.conf` into your question

Comment: added smb.conf to the answer

Comment: Please include the shares part too - at least the share that's failing

Comment: Ok, I've added that to the answer

Comment: Those shares can't possibly work. They're using `nobody` all over the place, in contractory places

Comment: Right, so synology hasn't written a valid file.  I'll try editing it, thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's the same on the ones that do work (nobody everywhere, but I'm guessing v1.0 works with that

Comment: Dmesg is: 
[ 5444.505445] CIFS VFS: Unable to select appropriate authentication method!
[ 5444.505447] CIFS VFS: \\192.168.1.27 Send error in SessSetup = -22
[ 5444.505457] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work in my case by allowing a minimum version of SMB as 1.0:

[image]